# MySQL: How do i update 50% of the rows, randomly selected?

Tags: mysql, random, percentage

I want to update 50% of the rows in a table, randomly selected. Is there any way to do that?

Edit: Just to clarify that it should always update 50% of the records, but of those 50% the rows must be randomly selected (not only the top 50% for instance). In other words, in avarage, every other record should be updated.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Should work like that:

```
UPDATE table SET x = y WHERE RAND() < 0.5
```

Yep, tested it, works. But of course, it is only 50% of the rows on average, not exactly 50%.

As written in the SQL 92 specification, the `WHERE` clause must be executed for each tuple, so the `rand()` must be reevaluated yielding the intended result (instead of either selecting all or no rows at all).

Excerpt from the specification (emphasis mine):

> General Rules
>
> 1) The `<search condition>` is applied to each row of T. The result
>               of the `<where clause>` is a table of those rows of T for which
>               the result of the `<search condition>` is true.
>
> 2) Each `<subquery>` in the `<search condition>` **is effectively executed for each row of T** and the results used in the application
>               of the `<search condition>` to the given row of T. If any executed
>               `<subquery>` contains an outer reference to a column of T, then
>               the reference is to the value of that column in the given row of
>               T.

Comment: Surely that would update *all* rows half the time and none at all for the other half?

Comment: And there's another problem: even if it works as planned, it might not update any rows - or update all the rows. RAND() is random, you know. )

Comment: If that does work, it only works on MySql (which is what the OP is using, I know) - definitely only `UPDATE`s all-or-nothing on MSSql.

Comment: well, it is still correct. You wrote "In other words, in avarage, every other record should be updated.". This is what is done here, ON AVERAGE :). Use raina77ow's answer if you want exactly 50%. However, the performance of his solution might not be too good for large tables (and due to the law of large numbers, my condition should get closer to 50% the bigger the table is).

Comment: @Widor: Looked it up in the spec, quoted in in my answer. The behaviour I mentioned is correct. If Mssql compiles this query to a all-or-nothing execution, then Mssql does not implement the standard correctly (wouldn't be the first MS product that doesn't care about standards, cf. IE and W3C standards...)

Comment: @Widor In fact it would work on other DBMSs as well. Of the popular products, only MSSQL doesn’t evaluate for every row.

Answer (score 7):

As I said, that's a long way, described in a sort of pseudocode. )

```
$x = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table;
@ids = SELECT id FROM some_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $x / 2;
UPDATE some_table WHERE id IN (@ids);
```

Comment: You can express that with one query. Then you can use standard SQL and without weird pseudocode extensions.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table SET volumnvalue = x WHERE RAND() <= 0.5
will result in very near to 50% of the records

Answer (score 0):

`RAND` should be random and you will not get a solid percentile split.

It would be better to use the modulus operator `%` to find every X number of items. This does work best with unique id columns like a Primary Key.

Try running this query, be sure to specify your table name and id column name:

Selecting every 2nd row, divisible by 2

`SELECT * from <your_table_name> where <id_column_name> %2=0`

Selecting every 6th row, divisible by 6

`SELECT * from <your_table_name> where <id_column_name> %6=0`

Once you hare happy that the `SELECT` results look good, you can change the query with update syntax to update the records, using the same `WHERE` clause